# Best way to remove duplicates from multidimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have an array:

```
double[][] points = {{0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0},  {2.0, 2.0}};
```

I want to create a new array without the duplicate entry `{1.0, 1.0}` - what would be the best way to do so?

Additional info:

- The array is sorted, but only by the first component, so it's possible to have

  ```
  {1.0, 2.0}, {1.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 2.0}
  ```

  That's how I get the data, I cannot change the initial sort mechanism.
- Two dimensions are the current limit, but the array can have thousands of points.

Comment: So... the dumb answer is `double[][] points2 = {{0.0, 0.0}, {1.0, 1.0},  {2.0, 2.0}};`  I'm sure that's not what you want!  Do you want to filter all duplicates?  If so, are you guaranteed that the array is sorted? ... Please clarify.

Comment: Have you tried to brute force it?

Comment: do u need to worry up to 2 dimension or it can go up to N dimension?

Comment: What sort of constraints are you operating under? If you have a small enough array, you could just do a double loop and compare each pair of elements.

Comment: @EdStaub: yes, that's what I want. Make `a b b c` `a b c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest answer: Compare the elements of the array pair-wise and remove the duplicates. This won't scale well, but it might not need to.

More complicated: Look at something like a [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). After you've sorted by first and then second elements of the subarrays, you can walk through the whole array and remove duplicates. This will scale better, but it could easily be overkill (depending on your situation).

Best (probably): Create a set of array elements. Walk through the array; for each element, check to see if it is already in the set. If it is, remove it from the array. If not, add it to the set and keep going. This is probably the best approach unless duplicating the array is a space issue.

Comment: I was thinking about the Set approach too, but I don't understand how to realize it as a Set lets my happily add `new double[] {1.0, 1.0}` twice.

Comment: @htorque: The add method in Java's set implementation returns true if an object was added successfully (ie, was not a duplicate) and false otherwise.

Comment: I know, but it returns `true` two both times.

Comment: besides which, it's only going to actually *store* one instance of the data, so you don't even need to check the results of the `add` method.  You could potentially add everything into the set, then ask for an array from the set.

Comment: @htorque- i would guess that it's because of how you're adding the elements to the set... I don't have a java compiler handy, but my  guess is that Set add() is comparing the object you're adding to the set (the double[] {...}) to the other elements in the set. However, I don't think primitive arrays have an equals() method, so all that's actually being compared is the element references, not the values of the elements.

Comment: Yes, the double[] type doesn't override equals() so you are comparing references. You will need to use a custom Comparator or some other means of comparing the elements.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make a set of all the points - just of the Y values for each X, because they're sorted on X.  Using a HashSet requires autoboxing every value - in efficiency matters, use [TDoubleHashSet](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/) instead.  This is probably somewhere near optimal - depending in part on frequency of duplicates.

This is as ordered as the input, but when there are multiple Y values for a given X value, they may be output in a different order than the input.

```
double prevPoint[];
// If efficiency matters, use Trove TDoubleHashSet instead.
HashSet<Double> set;
ArrayList<double[]> buffer;

double[][] filter(double[][] points)
{
    prevPoint = new double[]{Double.NaN, Double.NaN};
    set = new HashSet<Double>();
    // Allocate space as if there were no duplicates.
    // Tweak if expecting lots of dupes.
    buffer = new ArrayList<double[]>(points.length);
    for ( double[] point : points )
    {
        if ( prevPoint[0] != point[0] )
        {
            emitSet();
            set.clear();

        }
        set.add(point[1]);
        prevPoint = point;
    }

    // output hashset
    emitSet();

    return buffer.toArray(new double[buffer.size()][2]);
}

private void emitSet()
{
    for ( double y : set )
    {
        // optimize out array create for common case of only 1 y with the same x.
        // get rid of this complexity if efficiency not needed.
        if ( y == prevPoint[1] )
        {
            buffer.add(prevPoint);
        }
        else
        {
            buffer.add(new double[] {prevPoint[0], y});
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create set of 'array' elements. 'array' element should return equal true when contain equal elements insight.

Answer (score 1):

[What is the best way to remove duplicates in an Array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357421/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-duplicates-in-an-array-in-java)

Does this help at all?

Answer (score 1):

One simple thing you can do is check before you add a new element to your array.

Comment: Not an option. I need the duplicates to stay in the original, just one single function can work without them - with much less pain. ;)

Comment: thats too bad. there is no real efficient way to remove them. You would have to sort the array, or iterate through an array of N elements, N times for each element.

Comment: Can't you create both arrays at the time you populate the one with duplicates? The one you want without duplicates could be stored in a Set and you won't have to worry about checking for duplicates.