# Copy String value in array

Tags: java

can anyone help me on this.Lets say I have this array of string e.g.

```
String fruit[]={"apple","orange","kiwi","apple","kiwi"}
```

and I want to allocate it in each individual string variable. e.g. `String box1="apple"`, `String box2="oranges"`, `String box3="kiwi"`. How can I actually copy the value of array and store it in string variable. Can anyone give idea on how to do this.

Sorry! I forgot to add this to my question if it detect a duplicate in array it should ignore the duplicate value . e.g. String fruit{"apple","kiwi","apple"}. Output Box1="apple", Box2="kiwi".

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to?  The array removes the necessity of declaring/initializing multiple String variables.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add this to my question if it detect a duplicate in  array it should ignore the duplicate value . e.g. String fruit{"apple","kiwi","apple"}. Output Box1="apple", Box2="kiwi".

Comment: @user1110191 Are you trying to store each index of the array into a variable or display each unique index of the array?

Comment: If that's the case, then you would want to look at [this SO question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/357421/1079354).  I maintain that using an array to collect unique elements would be far easier, since you (normally) can't guarantee the number of elements you'll get, and it'll be far easier to code.

Comment: What I really want to do is read trough array and copy the value inside the array and each unique value in array will be stored in different variable. Similar to the example above. If it duplicate is detected then it will ignore the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the comments, it sounds like you want to get the unique strings from the array of strings. It can be easily achieved using a `Set` (`HashSet`).

e.g.

```
String[] fruits = {"apple", "orange", "kiwi", "apple", "kiwi"};
Set<String> uniqueFruits = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(fruits));
System.out.println(uniqueFruits);
```

That prints:

```
[orange, kiwi, apple]
```

Answer (score 4):

`String box1 = fruit[0];`
`String box2 = fruit[1];`

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an array access:

```
String box1 = fruit[0];
String box2 = fruit[1];
// etc.
```