# find duplicates of a vector and delete ,preserving the order of parallel vectors

Tags: java, vector, duplicates

this code is just a test to find duplicates of a vector and remove them ,while removing the correspoding objects of 2 other vectors

This gives as output an Arrayoutofindex in line 3.Do you have any suggestions?

```
        for (int k = 0 ; k < vA.size() ; k++)
            {                       
                Object a = vA.elementAt(0);
                Object b = vA.elementAt(k);
                if(a == b && k!=0)
                {
                int duplicate = vA.indexOf(b);
                vA.removeElementAt(duplicate);
                vB.removeElementAt(duplicate);
                vC.removeElementAt(duplicate);                    
                }
```

Comment: Try find out what the size of vA is before starting.

Comment: as Vipar said, vA.size() is going to be called each iteration, also sorted vector could possible improve performance but it needs calculation.

Comment: i corrected it .thnx very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (int k = 0 ; k <= vA.size() ; k++)`
k should run only from `0` to `va.size() - 1` because it is zero-based, i.e. the first index is `0`. Rewrite the loop statement as:

`for (int k = 0 ; k < vA.size() ; k++)`

Comment: This is excellent!Enlightment!problem solved!!;-)
1.000.000 thnx!

Answer (score 1):

According to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357421/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-duplicates-in-an-array-in-java) question, Which i advice you to read, as it explains the bets ways to remove duplicates from an array,

You can use the following methods :
The removeDuplicate Method:

```
    /** List order not maintained **/
public static void removeDuplicate(ArrayList arlList)
{
 HashSet h = new HashSet(arlList);
 arlList.clear();
 arlList.addAll(h);
}
```

And The removeDuplicateWithOrder Method:

```
    /** List order maintained **/
public static void removeDuplicateWithOrder(ArrayList arlList)
{
   Set set = new HashSet();
   List newList = new ArrayList();
   for (Iterator iter = arlList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
      Object element = iter.next();
      if (set.add(element))
         newList.add(element);
   }
   arlList.clear();
   arlList.addAll(newList);
}
```

Hopes theese help you somehow.

Comment: Creating a LinkedHashSet instead will preserve order, without the need to iterate through the original ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing vA.size() in **for** condition, and then trying to remove elements from vA inside loop. This is causing the exception.

Store vA.size in a seperate variable

```
int size = vA.size();
for (int k = 0 ; k <= size ; k++)
```

Then, inside loop, where ever you have

```
vA.removeElementAt(duplicate);
```

instead, store this is seperate new list.

```
toBeRemoved.add(b);//b is the element to be removed later
```

and remove all the toBeRemoved from vA after loop.

```
vA.removeAll(toBeRemoved );
```

EDITED:

Your new code will look like this-

```
int vASize = vA.size();
List vAToBeRemoved = new ArrayList();
for (int k = 0 ; k < vASize; k++)
            {                       
                Object a = vA.elementAt(0);
                Object b = vA.elementAt(k);
                if(a == b )
                {
                int duplicate = vA.indexOf(b);
                vAToBeRemoved.add(b);//elements to be removed later.
                vA.removeElementAt(duplicate);
                vB.removeElementAt(duplicate);
                vC.removeElementAt(duplicate);                    
                }
             }
vA.removeAll(vAToBeRemoved);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to remove dulplicate elements from vector

public static Vector removeDuplicateResults(Vector resultsVector) {

```
for(int i=0;i<resultsVector.size();i++){        
    for(int j=0;j<resultsVector.size();j++){            
            if(i!=j){                                            
                Object resultsVectorObject1 = resultsVector.elementAt(i);
                Object resultsVectorObject2 = resultsVector.elementAt(j);
                Object[] resultsObjectArray1 = (Object[]) resultsVectorObject1;
                Object[] resultsObjectArray2 = (Object[]) resultsVectorObject2;
                if(Arrays.equals(resultsObjectArray1, resultsObjectArray2))
                {
                    resultsVector.removeElementAt(j);
                }
            }
    }
}
return resultsVector;
```

}