# How to remove Duplicate values in ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, contacts

Now:

[image]

I want:

[image]

Code:

```
String[] contact = new String[contact_phoneList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < contact_phoneList.size(); i++) {
    contact [i] = contact_phoneList.get(i);
}
```

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912004/remove-duplicates-from-integer-array, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056729/java-remove-duplicates-from-an-array and even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357421/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-duplicates-in-an-array-in-java

Comment: Just use a `Set` and you'll be fine, or `contact_phoneList.stream().distinct().toArray(String[]::new);`

Comment: accept the answer if it helps..So it will help others

Comment: i accepted your answer. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) to remove duplicate values:

```
HashSet hs = new HashSet();
hs.addAll(contact_phoneList); // name of contact_phoneList from which you want to remove duplicates 
contact_phoneList.clear();
contact_phoneList.addAll(hs);
```

No need for a `for` loop

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. You are the best ^^

Comment: Welcome.......:)