# how to remove duplicate words from an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I am reading a file then calling a string[] method that breaks the line up into individual words, adds each word to an array of unique words (no duplicate words), and returns the array of unique words.

I cannot figure out how to only print each word once but here is what I have so far.

```
static public String[ ] sortUnique( String [ ] unique, int count)
{
    String temp;
    for(int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        temp = unique[i].replaceAll("([a-z]+)[,.?]*", "$1");;
        int j;
        for(j = i - 1; j>= 0 && (temp.compareToIgnoreCase(unique[j]) < 0);j--) {
            unique[j+1] = unique[j];
        }
        unique[j+1] = temp;
    }
    return unique;
}
```

And here is the data file.

```
    Is this a dagger which I see before me,
    The handle toward my hand? Come, let me clutch thee.
    I have thee not, and yet I see thee still.
    Art thou not, fatal vision, sensible
    To feeling as to sight? Or art thou but
    A dagger of the mind, a false creation,
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357421/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-duplicates-in-an-array-in-java

Comment: Turn the array into a set then convert it back to an array.

Comment: Idea: 1) sort the array 2) check each item against the next item 3) if `item[i]==item[i+1]` remove the duplicate.

Comment: As @tieTYT suggests, you should just add every word in the array to a set.  In Java, you can easily use one of the sets from the collections library.  I suggest a HashSet.

Comment: Ok once you compare the words, do you add the non-duplicates to another array and print that?

Comment: Not allowed?  Is this homework?

Comment: no I just haven't learned sets yet and I want to conquer arrays first.

Answer (score 4):

To read a file and remove duplicate words:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class WordReader {

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
      BufferedReader br =
         new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader( "F:/docs/Notes/Notes.txt" ));
      Set< String > words = new TreeSet<>();                // {sorted,unique}
      StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer( br );
      while( st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF ) {
         if( st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD ) {
            words.add( st.sval );
         }
      }
      System.out.println( words );
      br.close();
   }
}
```