# Checking whether you have two of the same elements in one integer array

Tags: java, arrays

How can you check (in Java) if you have two or more of the same elements in an integer array?

An example is if you want to get the mode of an array and the array might not have two or more of the same elements, so there wouldn't be any mode. In order to know that though, you would have to check whether you have two of the same elements in that array.

Comment: 1 Sort the array.  2. Compare each element with the following element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to remove duplicates in an Array in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357421/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-duplicates-in-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

Pre-java 8, you could use a `Set` as @kocko said (+1 to him). If you don't mind using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), here's a one-liner:

```
public static boolean hasDistinctElements(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.of(array).distinct().count() == array.length;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Set`, which doesn't allow duplicates.

1. Add all the elements of the array to the `Set`.
2. Compare the size of the `Set` with the size of the array.

   - if they are equal, then there are no duplicates
   - otherwise, there are duplicates.

For example:

```
int[] array = ...
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i : array) {
    set.add(i);
}
if (set.size() == array.length) {
    System.out.println("There are no duplicates");
} else {
    System.out.println("There are duplicates");
}
```

Comment: Wow. That's incredibly simple for something that seems like a hassle.

Comment: @vefthym `Arrays.asList` will create a `List<int[]>` so this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

One way is by looping,using nested loops.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length ; i++)
    for(int j=i; j<arr.length ; j++)
        if(arr[i] == arr[j])
            //two same elements detected
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method, which sorts the array and then checks for duplicates in the neighbors:

```
private boolean checkDuplicates(int[] array) {
    Arrays.sort(array);                        //sort the array in ascending order
    int prevElem = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
        if (array[i] == prevElem) { //if duplicates exist, they will be neighbors, since the array is sorted
            return true; //no need to examine the rest of the array elements, if a duplicate is found
        }
        prevElem = array[i];
    }
    return false; //if no duplicates are found, return true
}
```